# Filtering an array from another

Tags: arrays, swift, filter

"Is it possible to remove `for .. in`  (to make it more Swifty) ?

```
let arr1 = ["Bill", "John", "Richard", "Donald", "George"]
let arr2 = ["ill", "ck", "rd", "ld"]
var arr3 = Array<String>()

for str in arr2
{
    arr3 += arr1.filter{ $0.hasSuffix(str) }
}
debugPrint(arr3) // ["Bill", "Richard", "Donald"]
```

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is. Use the map function in conjunction with flatMap. If you want no doubled (e. g. when suffix is "d"), use Set():

```
let names = ["Bill", "John", "Richard", "Donald", "George"]
let suffixes = ["ill", "ck", "rd", "ld", "d"]
let namesWithSuffixes = Set(suffixes.map({ suffix in names.filter({ name in name.hasSuffix(suffix) }) }).flatMap({ $0 }))
```

But if you just want to get rid of the old for loop, you can use forEach():

```
var arr3 = [String]()
suffixes.forEach({ suffix in
    arr3 += names.filter({ $0.hasSuffix(suffix) })
})
```

Be aware that your original solution and the second one only causes 24 executions while the "swifty" map.filter.flatmap uses 29 executions.

[image]

Comment: you are welcome. It's been not that long since I learned about map and flatMap myself and in a lot of circumstances they are really helpful (e. g. when dealing with optionals. they are worth researching, trust me). I'm glad I was able to help

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't this be more concise and straightforward  ?

```
arr3 = arr1.filter{name in arr2.contains{name.hasSuffix($0)}}
```

Comment: Yes it is. Thank you